# Python: pass multiple columns to curve_fit function

Tags: python, multiple-columns, curve-fitting

I'm a newbie in Python and I'd appreciate if you could help me with this problem.

I'd like to iteratively pass each column of a big DataFrame (66 rows x 451 columns) to a curve_fit function.
The relevant part of my code is:

```
numcols = len(df.columns)
x = np.arange(0,33,0.5)

def func(x, a, b, c):
   return a*np.exp(-c*x)+b

for y in range(1, numcols):
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, df.iloc[:,y])
    a, c, b = popt[0], popt[1], popt[2]
    print (a, b, c)
```

Each of the columns in df should be a 'y' in the curve_fit function. The function should return the parameters a, b, c for each column/y. Is there a better way to code this? Any idea/suggestion or alternative methods are welcome.

Comment: An what is the problem? Could you show the entire code and which problems you encounter?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering! Now, the relevant part of my code is: `numcols = len(df.columns) x = np.arange(0,33,0.5) def func(x, a, b, c): return a*np.exp(-c*x)+b for y in range(1, numcols): popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, df.iloc[:,y]) a, b, c = popt[0], popt[1], popt[2] print (a, b, c)` . Each columns in df should be a 'y' in the curve_fit function. The function should return the parameters a, b, c for each column. Is there a better way to code this?

Comment: Please add this to your question (click the `edit` button), then it is easier to copy...